# Any benefits to using WCF for this?

Tags: wcf

I need to receive XML data from HttpPost requests. Currently I use HttpWebRequest to send the request and I convert the request to xml with StreamReader and XDocument.Parse.

Are there any benefits to switching over to WCF? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't plan to dramatically extend your application and only want to switch to WCF so that you are using it, no. :-)

WCF will give you some more flexibility - you could for example consume data in other data formats or from other transport formats (Named Pipes, ...)

Comment: You pretty much nailed it. I think I'll stick with my current method. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I hope i understood your question correctly !!!

The use of WCF lies where you know that both the sending as well as receiving end share the same data contract. 
I think in your case, using WCF will benefit if both are MS application and the contract is not supposed to change very frequently.

Comment: WCF is not MS-only - it works fine with any other server envirnoment! See http://www.kevingao.net/wcf-java-interop